# Facebook Custom Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

currently i'm using Omniauth-facebook and Koala to integrate with facebook, so posting status updates and pictures on users behalf is fairly straightforward.
I was wondering if anybody knows how to create a custom posts(for example like the posts that social cam or coupon sites create) from rails. 
Any guide or tutorial will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something similar to this post?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037655/are-custom-wall-posts-links-such-as-this-possible-with-the-api

To do this you need to use Open Graph:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: ThanksYeah exactly, is there a better tutorial than FB's developer site

Comment: Have you read all their documentation and looked at the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)?
The answer to your initial question is very well explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/)